# ExpandEnvironmentStringsA for UWP apps

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp

As per [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa), `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA` API is supposed to work for UWP apps too.

But when I am trying to use this API in my UWP app, I am getting "identifier not found error"

After debugging further and looking into processenv.h, I found this condition:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

That is why, my code is not able to find this API.
Any workaround for this? or are there any equivalent APIs that I can use for my scenario?

Comment: This macros means this api only work for desktop client, I'm afraid there is no other good  way

Comment: Hmm, But the doc says it works for UWP apps too right! what does that mean?

Comment: What device you test?

Comment: windows 8.1, it's a store application I am making changes to.

Comment: This api may only work for window 10.

Comment: Minimum supported client - Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps | UWP apps] - which is Windows NT. So, I think it should work for Win 8.1 too.

Comment: You could try to use it in UWP c++ winrt project to verify this.

Comment: Those API calls are guarded by `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP | WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM | WINAPI_PARTITION_GAMES)` for me (Win 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0). So yes, they are available when targeting the UWP. Are you using an outdated/unofficial Windows SDK?

Comment: Looks like things have changed starting with 10.0.16299.0. Prior to that SDK those API calls were only available under `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP`. I'm curious as to what happened here.

Comment: I think some of it is just Microsoft not making up their mind. Before allowing ACP to be UTF-8 there was not much use in allowing people to use the A functions for example.

Comment: @IInspectable The set of functions allowed in UWP apps expands over time. These changes are reflected in SDKs released after a function is added to the App partition, but since we don't have a time machine, older SDKs reflect the state when they were written.

Comment: @ray I assumed as much, but then why isn't availability version-gated in newer SDK's? Are we supposed to use the *specific* SDK version matching our UWP target version? And if the minimum supported version and the target version are different, how are we notified that any given API that was introduced in between is unavailable to our minimum supported UWP target?

Comment: When an API is added to the app partition, the next official SDK should reflect the new policy. (If not, let me know, and I'll ask them to fix it.) It controls whether Store will accept an app that calls it, so go ahead and call it even from old SDKs (e.g. via manual declaration, or opting into Desktop partition), and the Store will allow it. The Store doesn't check what SDK version you used. It checks what functions you called.

Comment: @RaymondChen Opting into Desktop partition as in, is it something that can be done in my code where the API call is happening? If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: `#define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP` or equivalent compiler option.

Comment: @ray I wasn't aware that the UWP API surface was sanctioned by the Store (as opposed to the individual target systems). That explains why the extended API surface for the `WINAPI_PARTITION_APP` need not be version-gated in newer SDKs. Thanks for bearing with me.